# Why does Map() fail on default texture despite UnifiedMemoryArchitecture and MapOnDefaultTextures

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11, direct3d11

[Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/direct3d-11-3-features) suggest, that default usage textures can be mapped on UMA architectures like Intel integrated graphics with Direct3D 11.3.

I tried to achieve this, but `Map()` always fails with `E_INVALIDARG`.

I am quite new to C++ and DirectX, but below is what I believe to be a minimal test case. Please don't hesitate to point out any stupidity I am committing.

I am running this on a notebook with Windows 10 1809, Intel Skylake i5-6300U with HD Graphics 520.

```cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <dxgi1_6.h>
#include <d3d.h>
#include <d3d11_4.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main()
{
    HRESULT res = S_OK;
    ID3D11Device *Dev = nullptr;
    ID3D11DeviceContext *Ctx = nullptr;
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL Fl;
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL fls[1] = { D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1 };

    res = D3D11CreateDevice(nullptr, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE, nullptr, D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG | D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_BGRA_SUPPORT, fls, 1, D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &Dev, &Fl, &Ctx);
    assert(res == S_OK);
    assert(Fl == D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1);

    ID3D11Device5 *Dev5 = nullptr;
    res = Dev->QueryInterface<ID3D11Device5>(&Dev5);
    assert(res == S_OK);
    Dev->Release();
    Dev = nullptr;

    ID3D11DeviceContext4 *Ctx4;
    res = Ctx->QueryInterface<ID3D11DeviceContext4>(&Ctx4);
    assert(res == S_OK);
    Ctx->Release();
    Ctx = nullptr;

    D3D11_FEATURE_DATA_D3D11_OPTIONS2 opts2;
    res = Dev5->CheckFeatureSupport(D3D11_FEATURE_D3D11_OPTIONS2, &opts2, sizeof(opts2));
    assert(res == S_OK);
    assert(opts2.MapOnDefaultTextures);
    assert(opts2.UnifiedMemoryArchitecture);

    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC1 texDesc = { 0 };
    texDesc.ArraySize = 1;
    texDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE | D3D11_BIND_UNORDERED_ACCESS;
    texDesc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ | D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
    texDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    texDesc.Height = 256;
    texDesc.Width = 256;
    texDesc.MipLevels = 1;
    texDesc.MiscFlags = 0;
    texDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    texDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    texDesc.TextureLayout = D3D11_TEXTURE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;
    texDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;

    byte mem[256 * 256 * 4];
    ZeroMemory(mem, 256 * 256 * 4);

    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA data = { 0 };
    data.pSysMem = mem;
    data.SysMemPitch = 256 * 4;

    ID3D11Texture2D1 *tex2d;
    res = Dev5->CreateTexture2D1(&texDesc, &data, &tex2d);
    assert(res == S_OK);

    D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE map = { 0 };
    // I believe at least one of these should succeed, but all fail
    res = Ctx4->Map(tex2d, 0, D3D11_MAP_READ, 0, &map);
    //res = Ctx4->Map(tex2d, 0, D3D11_MAP_WRITE, 0, &map);
    //res = Ctx4->Map(tex2d, 0, D3D11_MAP_READ_WRITE, 0, &map);
    assert(res == S_OK); // E_INVALIDARG
}
```

I believe the Map() call should succeed, but it fails with E_INVALIDARG.

**EDIT:** I tried `D3D11_TEXTURE_LAYOUT_ROW_MAJOR` and  `D3D11_TEXTURE_LAYOUT_64K_STANDARD_SWIZZLE` too, but then `CreateTexture2D1()` fails with E_INVALIDARG. Maybe my hardware doesn't support those modes?

Comment: Enable the Direct3D Debug Layer and you'll likely get more information in the debug output window. See [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/direct3d-sdk-debug-layer-tricks/). That said, the general answer here "Map a staging texture, copy it to your default texture'. Otherwise, use ``USAGE_DYNAMIC``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is described in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11_3/ns-d3d11_3-d3d11_texture2d_desc1):

> It is illegal to set CPU access flags on default textures without also setting TextureLayout to a value other than D3D11_TEXTURE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't see that. Unfortunately, if I specify one of the other two options, this time `CreateTexture2D1()` fails with E_INVALIDARG

Comment: @cgi In case of `D3D11_TEXTURE_LAYOUT_ROW_MAJOR` it is illegal to use non-zero bind flags, in case of `D3D11_TEXTURE_LAYOUT_64K_STANDARD_SWIZZLE` you should check whether it is supported by graphics driver by querying [D3D11_FEATURE_DATA_D3D11_OPTIONS2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11/ns-d3d11-d3d11_feature_data_d3d11_options2)

Comment: I thought I could save a copy operation when streaming frames to the video card, but now it seems, what I wanted to do can't be done and what could be done like wouldn't help...

Answer (score 0):

This method may fix your problems [in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11/nf-d3d11-id3d11devicecontext-map#null-pointers-for-pmappedresource).

> The pMappedResource parameter may be NULL when a texture is provided that was created with D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT, and the API is called on an immediate context. This allows a default texture to be mapped, even if it was created using D3D11_TEXTURE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED. Following this API call, the texture may be accessed using ID3D11DeviceContext3::WriteToSubresource and/or ID3D11DeviceContext3::ReadFromSubresource.

Psudocode like this:

```
deviceContext->Map(defaultWithCPUAccesssTexture, 0, D3D11_MAP_WRITE, 0, NULL);
device3->WriteSubResource(defaultWithCPUAccesssTexture, 0, NULL, pData, rowPitch, depthPitch);
deviceContext->UnMap(defaultWithCPUAccesssTexture, 0);
```

Also read from default texture is the same way like write.